# IOS JSON AND TEXT JSON data

Tags: iphone, ios, json, ipad

In my iOS application I have to use `json` file to get data on `map` and I have all the data already .Which should be best way to use json file on my condition

1. If i create `JSON WebService` and get the data from that json webservice
2. Directly `Text JSON` inside the app

which should be best way to do that ...can you also explain me the `PRO and CONES` for this condtion

Comment: Directly Text JSON inside the app, is the best way.

Comment: y can explain me ..y not web service

Comment: because, if it is fix then why you call the WebService, it take too much time when Internet speed is slow. What about when Internet is not available. So if it is fix then used Second Way.

Comment: If you don't foresee the need to update the data (without reloading the app) then installing the data with the app is obviously a better choice (assuming that you're talking about a single JSON file of maybe a few MB in size, max).  If you expect to update the data then it should be downloaded from the net and "cached" with your app.  You should also use the download/cache approach if you have a lot of data (eg, map information for a large area) and the user would typically only use a part of it at any one time.

Comment: @HotLicks can you please explain me more about this cache approch..I am unaware of that..

Comment: Basically, you download the file the first time you need it, then store it in the Caches directory.  Next time that you need it, first check if it in the Caches directory -- if not download it.  Windows will delete things in the Caches directory as the phone gets tight on storage, so you don't need to worry too much about deleting old files.  Break a big file into segments by alphabet or region or whatever (based on likely reference patterns) and only download the parts you need right away -- will shorten download times and save storage.

Comment: Thanks for the info.. But can you please clear this.I was downloading some image in documents directory...instead of this I used cache directory.means this should not be delete even on deletion of app..right?.. then I removed my app from simulator ..then y my cache folder get deleted on removing app. and location of cache folder was in ~5.0/application/../library/caches